# $mysql_ disspearing?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Im coding a installer, anyhow .. ive ran into trouble when it.. creates the global.php file, the $mysql_ connection does not show up in file while everything else does?

I'm trying to insert this

```
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_name = '-----';
$mysql_pass = '-----';
```

in the global.php it comes out with:

```
 = 'localhost';
 = 'root';
 = '-----';
 = '-----';
```

Notice $mysql_ missing?

This is the code in the installer:

```
    $db_name = trim($_POST['db_name']);
    $db_user = trim($_POST['db_user']);
    $db_pass = trim($_POST['db_pass']);
    $db_host = trim($_POST['db_host']);     

    $handle = fopen($setting['config']['folder'] . $setting['config']['file'], 'w');

$input = "<?php



$mysql_host = '".$db_host."';
$mysql_user = '".$db_user."';
$mysql_name = '".$db_name."';
$mysql_pass = '".$db_pass."';
?>

";

fwrite($handle, $input);
fclose($handle);
```

Can someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = "<?php
\$mysql_host = '$db_host';
\$mysql_user = '$db_user';
\$mysql_name = '$db_name';
\$mysql_pass = '$db_pass';
?>";
```

In double quoted strings $ sign is like concatenation. If you want insert dollar sign in a string you should escape it with `\` backslash.

Comment: Now, the $db_host wont pick up from the script above. it now shows 
$mysql_host = '';
$mysql_user = '';
$mysql_name = '';
$mysql_pass = '';

Comment: @user2172990 are you sure that `$db_host`, `$db_user` ... vars defined properly / isn't empty? Problem isn't in a code above. Turn on all PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using double-quotes in the string, PHP will interpret variable names it sees in the string, and output the value of the variable rather than the variable name.

This is a php feature intended to allow you to embed variables inside a string without having to open and close the string repeatedly. Ironically, that's exactly what you're doing with your actual PHP variables.

You have two options:

1. Switch to using single quotes for the string. This will work exactly as you have it.
2. Keep using double quotes, but escape the `$` symbol with a backslash where you don't want PHP to interpret it.

   If you do keep using double-quotes, you also have the option as I said to embed your variables in the string, so you don't need to keep opening and closing the quotes. In this case, your code would look like this:

   ```
   $input = "<?php

   \$mysql_host = '{$db_host}';
   \$mysql_user = '{$db_user}';
   \$mysql_name = '{$db_name}';
   \$mysql_pass = '{$db_pass}';
   ?>
   ";
   ```

One other thing you need to be aware of though: You're not escaping the `$db_xx` variables when you read them from `$_POST`. This means, for example, that if the user has a name or password with a quote character in it, it will result in invalid PHP code being generated.

Furthermore, it would be possible for the user to use this error as a technique to inject arbitrary PHP code into the system. Although this script is clearly intended for use only when setting up the system in the first place, this is a major security flaw in your code which should be corrected.